# Different Data for Different users

Tags: php, dashboard

i have created a dashboard to which all my users are being redirected to after login. Now, how do i display different data for different people?

Say for example, I want to display an additional object which would be a rounded rectangle for user John. I don't want the rounded rectangle to appear for user Chris.

How do i do that? Can you give me a brief overview with any links if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: It probably depends on how your login system works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [ACL management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).

There are [a lot of php script for that](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+acl).

I use [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.introduction.html).